# Hidden message in rap text: "Yo Gandhi, Dupe Bounce!"

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

A rapper released a teaser for his upcoming track, claiming it's some deep stuff. Here's the image he uploaded, which appear to be part of the lyrics:

[image]

It appears to be saying "YO GANDHI DUPE BOUNCE" in some sort of weird 3x3 typeface. I don't know what a "dupe bounce" is (some kind of dance?), why Gandhi is involved or why he should do the dupe bounce, and I'm not sure if I want to know. I don't think it's important.

---

What I **do** want to know is **what the title of the song is**. He said it "is sticky".

---

Here's a transcription of the image, with whitespace removed.

```
Y YYYYGG  G GGGGG R RRRRGG G GRRRRRRRR RRRG GGGGBBBBBB
 Y Y YG GGGGG GG GRRR R G GG GRRRRR RRRR RG GG GB  BB
 Y YYYGGGG GG GGG R RRRRGG GGGR  RRRRRRRRRGGGG GBBBBBB
```

---

Hint #1

> - The red, green and yellow colors were taken directly from the Puzzling.SE logo and don't hold any particular information in themselves (other than the fact that they have to be distinguishable from one another, since each color stands for something different). The only deliberate choice was the blue color.
>  - The answer has 9 letters

Hint #2

> - All different operations (rgby) have the same basic concept
>  - Result is in the same 3x3 typeface
>  - I didn't come up with anything innovative for this, it's using well-known "methods" in a way that fits the presentation.

Comment: Just a thought, rot13(gur qvssrerag pbybhef znl ersre gb qvssrerag genafsbezngvbaf. Vg frrzf gb zr gung gur terra znxrf zber frafr vs vg'f zveeberq hc, fb gur terra yrggref jbhyq fnl OKUO - OB - BU.)

Comment: I discovered you could do this, it might be of some help to others: rot13(Jvgu gur lryybj yrggref bs "LB", ol tbvat yrsg gb evtug naq hc gb qbja jvgu rnpu ebj naq pbairegvat vg gb zbefr, jr trg "..- ... .-" juvpu fcryyf "HFN".)

Comment: @WoomyRogue That's a coincidence, unfortunately.

Comment: @LukasRotter rot13(Jryy V qvq fbzr fgrcf naq raqrq hc jvgu 'RAVTZNGVP' juvpu zngpurf gur gurzr ohg sryg n ovg sbeprq. V nffhzr vapbeerpg?)

Comment: @Amoz Not what I intended, no.

Comment: Is this the title: "YGGRGRRGB"?

Comment: @fairopshotgun No, that would be pretty unfair. The "is sticky" is meant to verify the result

Comment: @LukasRotter I've tried a method but only thing that makes sense, so far, is if the first word is rot(565666656)? Probably off track if it's not..

Comment: @Prim3numbah Did something go wrong with your spoiler? If it's any number, I'm afraid it's off track. I'll drop a hint shortly.

Comment: @LukasRotter Rot5. I just tried to make it a bit cryptic. V npghnyyl zrnag "N"

Comment: @Prim3numbah That's the correct first word, so I'll change my mind and will **not** drop a hint shortly xD

Comment: Ok :) I'll try to make sense of the rest

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The song is called:

> **A BOX OF GOO**!

To find this:

> Take each coloured pair of consecutive letters and apply a specific operation to the 9 cells which make up their glyphs, as follows:
>
>  Yellow = XOR (use the squares 'lit up' in *only one* letter glyph)
>  Green = OR (use the squares 'lit up' in *either* letter glyph)
>  Red = AND (use the squares 'lit up' in *both* letter glyphs)
>  Blue = XNOR (use the squares 'lit up' in *both or neither* of the letter glyphs)

This results in the following calculations:

> [image: Calculating the final letters]
>
>  ...and the 'sticky' answer can be read off: **A BOX OF GOO**!

Comment: Yes, good job :) As a sidenote, the blue color is the inverse of the yellow one (i. e. Opposite = not xor = xnor)