# Hidden message in rap text II: "Ya, a ray 'ave july joy!"

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, geometry

**This puzzle is inspired by [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110665/hidden-message-in-rap-text-yo-gandhi-dupe-bounce) by @LukasRotter. Hopefully you don't mind me using similar (well, basically the same) format as yours, Mr. Rotter! ;)**

The same rapper released another teaser for his other upcoming track, saying that it is an exciting release. Here's the image he uploaded, which appears to be part of the lyrics:

[image]

It appears to be saying **"YAARAYAVE JYULYY JOY"** in a slightly different (but equally weird) 3x3 typeface, which is kinda like a homophone for **"Ya, a ray (h)'ave July joy!"**. I don't know what a "July joy" is (maybe a specific type of emotion one feel in a particular period of time?), how a light ray provokes emotions, or why he chose to write this sentence in such a weird way. But, after seeing the rapper's last clue, I don't think it should be interpreted like this anyway.

---

I still want to **find the title of this song**. He didn't give any hint this time. Can you help me?

---

**Feel free to share your ideas in the comments! Sharing what you tried that didn't work can also be helpful for other solvers!**

**Hint 1:**

> Hmmm... The jagged edges of the letters make me think of a jigsaw puzzle.

**Hint 2:**

> Hmmm... Why did he choose to omit the spaces in the first row?

**Decisive Hints:**

> -the answer contains 9 letters as well
>  -I added the tag [geometry](/questions/tagged/geometry)
>  -someone left a comment under the original post, "Looking forward to your new album!"
>  -the grey color was chosen delibrately, but it's more like a bonus question than a hint

**Very Decisive Hints:**

> -the answer is in a 3 by 5 pixel font.
>  -the answer contains spaces, but the immediate result after decoding **does not** contain spaces.

**Some Other Very Decisive Hints:**

> Try to consider certain letters as a whole (instead of pixel by pixel), then perform certain operations on it.\

**Additional hints:**

> Perhaps a few of the pixels are not necessary...
>  Try to deconstruct and reconstruct! And while reconstructing, think about the hints above. Maybe listing some restrictions of the reconstructed pattern might help?

Comment: (+1) Can't wait for the full release!

Comment: @LukasRotter :D

Comment: I've been looking at this on and off, but despite the rather explicit hints I haven't been able to get anywhere. I think rot13(gung gjb fznyy yrggref pna or wbvarq vagb n ynetre, svir-ol-guerr yrggre. Wbvavat gjb yrggref zrnaf gb cynpr gurz nybatfvqr jvgubhg bireynccvat fb gung gurl svg frnzyrffyl. Sbe rknzcyr, bar pna fjnc gur erq HY cnve gb YH, chfu gur gbj yrggref gbtrgure naq ebgngr gurz gb trg na R. Yvxrjvfr, gjb fznyy N'f pna znxr bar ynetr N.).

Comment: More rot13(Fvapr gurer ner na bqq ahzore bs terra naq oynpx sentzragf, V qba'g guvax gung n arj yrggre pnaabg nyjnlf or znqr sebz gjb cnegf bs gur fnzr pbybhe. Creuncf gur pbybhef vaqvpngr ebgngvbaf, bar cbffvoyr dhnegre-ghea sbe rnpu pbybhe. Juvpu cvrprf fubhyq or wbvarq gura? Gjb nqwnprag cvrprf bs rnpu ebj? Gung jvyy tvir zr bireynccvat, naq V qba'g jnag gb bireync bs syvc cvrprf, orpnhfr bs gur wvtfnj uvag. Jung nobhg gur fcnprf? Nyfb, gur gjb qvssrerag W'f va gur bevtvany znxr zr jbaqre jurgure rdhvinyrag erfhyg yrggref nyjnlf ybbx gur fnzr.)

Comment: rot13((Sbe jung vg'f jbegu: V'ir eraqrerq gur yrggref va n tencuvpf cebtenz jurer V pna rnfvyl ebgngr naq zbir gurz.))

Comment: @MOehm That's definitely a good place to start! ;)

Comment: I really didn't expect this to remain unsolved and unanswered for so long! It was literally my first instinct when I saw the original puzzle...

Comment: @JerryDean Then this looks like a job for... @codewarrior0!!